# Function, for, if(Задание)

Tags: javascript

[image]
Что не так? Только изучаю JS. Нужна помощь и объяснение.

```
function factorial(number){
  let result;
  if(number === 0)
    return 1;
  else if(number !== 0 && number > 0)
    for(let j = 0; j > number; j++)
      result =  j * number;
}
factorial(0);
factorial(1);
factorial(2);
factorial(4);
factorial(5);
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, напишите в вопрос код  текстом, напишите также текстом что ожидается, что получается и что не так.

Comment: Под вопросом есть кнопка "Править". И в вопросе можно оформлять как код, так и цитаты

Comment: `let j = 0;` — ошибка раз (умножение начинается с нуля - всё дальше будет нулем), `j > number;` — ошибка двас: Выражение j > number сразу дает false и цикл прерывается. Должно быть `j <= number`.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Answer (score 2):

Как насчет рекурсии?

```js
function factorial(number) {
  if (number < 0) // если пользователь ввел отрицательное число
    return 0; // возвращаем ноль
  if (number === 0) // если пользователь ввел ноль,
    return 1; // возвращаем факториал от нуля - не удивляетесь, но это 1)
  else // Во всех остальных случаях
    return number * factorial(number - 1); // делаем рекурсию.
}
console.log(factorial(100));
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function factorial(number) {
  let result = 1;
  for (let j = 2; j <= number; j++)
    result *= j;
  return result;
}

console.log(factorial(0));
console.log(factorial(1));
console.log(factorial(2));
console.log(factorial(4));
console.log(factorial(5));
```

Comment: Спасибо, а можно разъяснение?

Comment: Как вы решили момент с factorial(0)? Ведь если он равен 0, то факториал числа равен 1, в цикле нигде этого не указано, и if отсутствует. И почему переменная j равна именно 2-м?

Comment: @Alexander Вoзьмите листок бумаги и проследите по шагам, что делает функция, когда `number` равно `0`.

Comment: @Alexander "почему переменная j равна именно 2-м" - потому что на единицу можно не умножать